# Remove borders around textarea and input fields?

Tags: html, css

I have the following problem - my textarea and input fields are semitransparent, but I can't remove the border around them completely. I tried making transparent borders or specifying `border: none;` but they do not disappear (see the image below)

Anyone knows a good solution?

Thank you!

[image]

Comment: It could be `border`...or it could be `box-shadow`...Show us your code (jsfiddle)

Comment: Could also be `outline`

Comment: Or all on the same time, look my response i remove all concerned attribute.

Answer (score 2):

Try this :

```
textarea {
    border: none;
    overflow: auto;
    outline: none;

    -webkit-box-shadow: none;
    -moz-box-shadow: none;
    box-shadow: none;
}
```

Comment: Why are you reset overflow ?

Comment: To remove border highlighting provided because of the scrollbars .

Answer (score 0):

First, be sure that the borders are indeed applied on textarea, input elements and not other elements such as their parents.

Then, make sure that the border styles are not applied with `!important` in css files on textarea, input elements.

Finally

```
$('textarea, input').css('border', 'none !important');
```

Comment: It would be a better practice to do it with CSS classes rather than using JS.

Answer (score 0):

Why are you asking for javascript ?

Try this :

```
// No border
border-width: 0;

// No box shadow 
-webkit-box-shadow: none;
-moz-box-shadow: none;
box-shadow: none;

// No outline (ex: blue shadow on Mac OsX on focus)  
outline: 0;
```

Comment: Because maybe some people have some hacks

Comment: So add !important. But it's a hack to hack hacks.. :/

Answer (score 0):

If you have a class with the specific rules you can use:

```
$("#idTextarea").addClass("classYouNeed");
```

if you have only remove the border

```
$("#idTextarea").css('border', 'none');
```

Even if you want to use only JavaScript:

```
document.getElementById("#idTextarea").style.borderStyle = "none";
```

Comment: All this javascript to do CSS stuff ^^

Comment: Yes, I know but sometimes you need to change something without touch the css file. Of course it is better work with css but it is depend your permission in the app

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps a bit heavy-handed, but rather than "remove" the borders, why not simply specify their colour as being the same as the background colour?